# divide a number by 2 recursively

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I have been puzzled in a recursive problem.

I want to divide given numbers (e.g. 20)in two parts both containing 1 to half and half to end, now these two sub array should be divide in the same manner i.e. 1 to half and half to end until we traverse all elements.

Please suggest me how to achieve this either recursively or through iteration.

---

<sup>*Transferring comment to question.*</sup>

Suppose input is 1 and 20. The output would be something like:

1. 20/2 = 10 now we have two set of numbers (1 and 10) and (11 and 20)
2. 10/2 = 5, second half of (20+10)/2=15.

This iteration will run in the same manner until we traverse all the numbers between 1 and 20.

Comment: please note that sub arrays would be min to half and half to end

Comment: Do you want to divide numbers or recursively go through arrays?

Comment: I want to divide numbers and find all the numbers which are divide by 2 in min and max numbers.

Comment: Please show expected output for a specific input.

Comment: suppose input is 1 and 20:

output would be something like:

1) 20/2 = 10
now we have two set of numbers (1 and 10) and (11 and 20)
2) 10/2 = 5, second half of (20+10)/2=15
this iteration will run same manner until we traverse all the numbers between 1 and 20

Comment: In the second step, don't you have four ranges: 1..5, 6..10, 11..15, 16..20?  Whether that's true or not, you've got some explaining to do — it is not at all clear what output you want.  Please show the actual printed output for the example of `1` and `20`.

Comment: HI Jonathan Leffler....You got exactly what I mean to say,

 in the second iteration i would have these four ranges 1..5, 6..10, 11..15, 16..20...similarly in the further iteration we will have more sub sets....
and at each step i want to insert one number in list
e.g. in first step insert 10 in the list, in the second step 5 and 15 will be inserted in the list, in the third step want to insert 3,8,13,18 in the list...this iteration will go on until we insert all the numbers in the list....
please help me to achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: where is your try

Comment: What do you want to insert in the fifth, last step - `1  2  4  5  6  7  9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 19 20`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> what i needed is...(1)  in the first iteration i want 10. (2) in the
>   second iteration i want  5, 15. (3) in the third iteration i want
>   3,8,13,18. and so on. –  user4365176

I found a tool (in my libraries) which I used to transfer the contents of a  vector (of non-decreasing integers) TO a binary tree SUCH-THAT the simple binary tree would be (mostly) balanced.

Here is a version of that code which I simplified for your purpose. This snippet is a method in a class, so the undefined variables prefixed with 'm_' (m_tree, m_ss, m_R) are data attributes of that class.  m_tree is instance of my home-grown-simple binary tree, with method "insertVal(size_t i)", m_ss is a pointer to a std::stringstream, and m_R is the user input number, the Range.

'genSeqRR()' is recursive.  It chops a range in half, then processes the right then the left (somewhat in the form of depth-first-in-order.   Currently, the sequence is perhaps slightly biased. Not sure how to describe.  See Note 2 (in code).

I also inserted these sequences to an AVL tree (from rosettacode.org/wiki) and the result were disappointing.  Possibly not wrong, but not useful here.

You might try this insert sequence with a RedBlack Trees.

---

example outputs after the code:

```
// Generate a Sequence of size_t values over a fixed limited Range,
// Recursively using binary-pattern through the range, to achieve approximate
// balance when inserting into a simple binary tree.
//
// Note1: 'index' is range (0..N-1), value to insert is (indx+1) i.e 1..N
// Note2: prefer to insert bigger indx first
//
void genSeqRR(size_t depth, const size_t si,  const size_t bi)
  {
     size_t rng = bi - si; // big indx - small indx
     switch (rng)
     {

     default: // 3 or more elements, insert mi, and recurse
     {
        size_t delta = rng / 2;
        size_t    mi = si + delta; // mid index

        (void)m_tree->insertVal(mi+1);  // Note1

        // if(m_ss)
        *m_ss << "    rng:" << std::setw(3) << rng
              << "   dpth:" << std::setw(3) << depth  // depth of genSeqRR
              << "   iVal:" << std::setw(3) << mi+1
              << std::endl;

        // Note2
        genSeqRR (depth+1, mi+1, bi); // recurse on max - (middle + 1) thru biggest index
        genSeqRR (depth+1, si, mi-1); // recurse on min - smallest index thru (middle - 1)
     }
     break;

     case 0: // 1 elment
     {
        (void)m_tree->insertVal (si+1); // Note1

        // if(m_ss)
        *m_ss << "    rng:__1"
              << "   dpth:" << std::setw(3) << depth
              << "   iVal:" << std::setw(3) << si+1 << std::endl;
     }
     break;

     case 1: // 2 consecutive elements
     {
        // Note1,  Note2
        (void)m_tree->insertVal(bi+1);
        (void)m_tree->insertVal(si+1);

        // if(m_ss)
        *m_ss << "    rng:__2"
              << "   dpth:" << std::setw(3) << depth
              << "   iVal:" << std::setw(3) << si+1 << std::setw(3) << bi+1  << std::endl;
     }
     break;

     }// switch
  } // void genSeqRR()
```

with range m_R = 20,

```
genSeqRR (1, 0, (m_R-1)); // start recursion over whole range
```

output:

```
Anchor->showTallView()
                   '1' 
             '2' 
                         '3' 
                   '4' 
       '5' 
                   '6' 
             '7' 
                         '8' 
                   '9' 
 '10' 
                   '11' 
             '12' 
                         '13' 
                   '14' 
       '15' 
                         '16' 
                   '17' 
             '18' 
                         '19' 
                   '20'
```

with range m_R = 19,

```
genSeqRR (1, 0, (m_R-1)); // start recursion over whole range
```

output:

```
Anchor->showTallView()
                   '1' 
             '2' 
                         '3' 
                   '4' 
       '5' 
                   '6' 
             '7' 
                         '8' 
                   '9' 
 '10' 
                   '11' 
             '12' 
                         '13' 
                   '14' 
       '15' 
                   '16' 
             '17' 
                         '18' 
                   '19'
```

with range m_R = 19,

```
Anchor->showTallView()
                   '1' 
             '2' 
                   '3' 
       '4' 
                   '5' 
             '6' 
                         '7' 
                   '8' 
 '9' 
                   '10' 
             '11' 
                         '12' 
                   '13' 
       '14' 
                   '15' 
             '16' 
                         '17' 
                   '18'
```

Comment: HI DOUGLAS O. MOEN,  Thanks for your kind reply....here you printed (min+1) and (max-1) until (max<min)...it works perfectly well.
but what i needed is...(1) in the first iteration i want 10. (2) in the second iteration i want 5, 15. (3) in the third iteration i want 3,8,13,18. and so on.